# Android Studio open intent and data input

Tags: android, android-intent, input

I open the settings using intent on Android studio. I would like to enter data in a part of these settings that are opened later. How can I do that?

After the object is submitted, the empty space (names, type, etc.) in the images must be filled.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuarS.png)

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS");                              
startActivity(intent);
```

Like this :

An intent surrender.
A settings page opens.
I will send the variable with the intent.
I will place this variable on the settings page that opens.
For example, I will send "Recep" to the name field.
When we initiate the intention, the name field will be filled with the name we sent.

Comment: I tried the answers to this message. But I did not succeed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to achieve the above !! I tested this on **Kitkat** and **lollipop** devices , On both of them its working

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**UPDATE**

```
public static void showDataRoamingScreen()
 {
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
{
    _showSettingScreen("android.settings.DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS");
}
else
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
    ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");
    intent.setComponent(cName);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Reference.getAppContext().startActivity(intent);
}
}



 public static void showDataMobileScreen()
 {
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);//android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS //Intent.ACTION_MAIN
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Reference.getAppContext().startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    showDataRoamingScreen();
}
}


protected static void _showSettingScreen(String intentStr)
{
try
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(intentStr);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Reference.getAppContext().startActivity(intent);
}
catch (Exception e) {Reference.showToast(e.toString(), true);}
}
```

Comment: @RecepKara is this the solution to your question?

Comment: I am trying. But I'm getting an error. Reference.getSystem does not recognize the partition.

Comment: @RecepKara try it now

Comment: I know I've made you very hard. But unfortunately I failed.
- _showSettingScreen,
. -Reference.getAppContext () startActivity (intent);

I've had problems with these sections

Comment: @RecepKara it was my mistake, i forget to mention that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,example.class);
i.putExtra("id", "1");
startActivity(i);
```

latter you can retrieve using .

```
 String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

for passing datas with intent

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
Intent intent  = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
intent.putExtra("key", value);
startActivity(intent);
```